# If body has class, then redirect with angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am pretty new to AngularJS.

What would be the best way to detect if body has class "lt-ie9", and if this is true, then redirect the user to different subpage?

PS: Somebody told me to use use the " .run" method. What do you think about it?

Comment: I've never used AngularJS, but that sounds great. Why don't you try it out and come back with results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.run()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module#run) method is fired when all modules have finished loading. It's the closest thing to a 'main' method that AngularJS provides. It wouldn't be unreasonable to handle this scenario here.

```
angular.module("MyApp", []).
    run(function ($document, $location) {
      if ($document.find("body").hasClass("lt-ie9")) {
        $location.path("...");
      }
    });
```